# How do I get a valeu from a async function and pass it to a component ( React )?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, components, fetch

So, I'm trying to get this value from a async function, so far, so good, but, I can't get this value and pass it to my component as shown:

- I'm using react with Ionic 5.

```js
const IdeiaId: React.FC<projectIdInterface> = (props) => {
  const [idProjeto, setIdProjeto] = useState<number>(0);
  const [ativo, setAtivo] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [criadoEm, setcriadoEm] = useState<string>("");
  const [imgIdeia, setImgIdeia] = useState<string>("");
  const [descricao, setDescricao] = useState<string>("");
  const [subtitulo, setSubtitulo] = useState<string>("");
  const [titulo, setTitulo] = useState<string>("");
  const [status, setStatus] = useState<string>("");

  useIonViewWillEnter(() => {
    const idIdeia = +props.match.params.id;
    let resp = Requests.lerIdeia(idIdeia);
    resp.then((res) => {
      if (res && res.ok) {
        if (res.data) {
            res = res.data;
            res[OBJKEYS.projects.proPk] ? setIdProjeto(res[OBJKEYS.projects.proPk]) : setIdProjeto(0);
            res[OBJKEYS.projects.imagePath] ? setImgIdeia(OBJKEYS.images.imageUrl + res[OBJKEYS.projects.imagePath]) : setImgIdeia(OBJKEYS.images.defaultAvatar);
            res[OBJKEYS.projects.proAtivo] ? setAtivo(res[OBJKEYS.projects.proAtivo] === '1') : setAtivo(false);
            res[OBJKEYS.projects.criadoEm] ? setcriadoEm(res[OBJKEYS.projects.criadoEm]) : setcriadoEm('');
            res[OBJKEYS.projects.descricao] ? setDescricao(res[OBJKEYS.projects.descricao]) : setDescricao('');
            res[OBJKEYS.projects.subtitulo] ? setSubtitulo(res[OBJKEYS.projects.subtitulo]) : setSubtitulo('');
            res[OBJKEYS.projects.titulo] ? setTitulo(res[OBJKEYS.projects.titulo]) : setTitulo('');
            res[OBJKEYS.status.status] ? setStatus(res[OBJKEYS.status.status]) : setStatus('');
        } else {
          console.log(res.errors);
        }
      }
    });
  });

  console.log(idProjeto);
  return (
    <IonPage>
      <Header name="Ideia"></Header>
      <ProjetoImageSlides idProjeto={idProjeto} key={0} />
      <IonContent>
        <div></div>
        <h1>{titulo}</h1>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};
```

What is the best way to solve this?
So, I'm getting this value 'idProjeto' from a async function and I want to pass it in the 'ProjetoImageSlides' component, but It dont update when the value change, because it loaded before, What can I do? Should I load it after get the value?

Comment: Please explain more, what do you want?

Comment: So, I'm getting this value 'idProjeto' from a async function and I want to pass it in the 'ProjetoImageSlides' component, but It dont update when the value change, because it loaded before, What can I do? Should I load it after get the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution is to conditional rendering ProjetoImageSlides like this:

```
 return (
    <IonPage>
      <Header name="Ideia"></Header>
      {idProjeto && <ProjetoImageSlides idProjeto={idProjeto} key={0} />}
      <IonContent>
        <div></div>
        <h1>{titulo}</h1>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
```

In this way, the ProjetoImageSlides component will not render if the value of idProjeto stays zero (which is **false**)

but the best solution is to handle this from inside ProjetoImageSlides so that it updates if the idProjeto changed.

Comment: I did the verification inside my component and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: I just don't know why my component is being called multiple times

Comment: if called multiple times but not rendered more than one time in the screen, then this is because any change in the state will re render the component and this is normal from react behavior. but the best practice is to reduce the number of times your components called.